# problems with async function react-native

Tags: multithreading, react-native, redux, promise

i need to fetch some data before render my template and i tryied 2 differents methods, but the both failed.

this is the first one with sync transaction:

```
if (loginData) {
    loginGet(userData!.cpf, loginData.access_token)
      .then((data: UserAzureInterface) => {
        console.log(JSON.stringify(data));
        dispatchUserAzureSuccess(data, dispatch);
      })
      .catch(_error => {});
  } else {
    navigation.navigate('Login');
  }

return (
    <>
      <ProfileIndexTemplate onSubmit={onSubmit} userData={userData} />
    </>
  );
```

and this is the async transaction:

```
const getLoginAzure = async () => {
    if (loginData) {
      const loginAzureData = await loginGet(
        userData!.cpf,
        loginData.access_token,
      );
      console.log(JSON.stringify(loginAzureData));
      dispatchUserAzureSuccess(loginAzureData, dispatch);
    }
  };

  getLoginAzure();

return (
    <>
      <ProfileIndexTemplate onSubmit={onSubmit} userData={userData} />
    </>
  );
```

From profileIndexTemplate im trying to get my UserAzureInterface but i got undefined data, because my loginGet at the screen are not finish yet.

```
const loginAzure = useSelector(({ userAzure }: AppState) => userAzure.data);
  console.log(`meu login azure: ${JSON.stringify(loginAzure)}`);
```

Can i see the error, but i cant figure how to solve that. any one can helps me?

Comment: You can call the fetch logic into the `constructor` method.  [React Native Lifecycle](https://miro.medium.com/max/859/1*u8hTumGAPQMYZIvfgQMfPA.jpeg)
As you can see in the React Native Lifecycle methods, `constructor` always calls before the render method.

Comment: thanks bro, you are right!

Answer (score 1):

i got it! to solve this problem this is what i did:

```
 useEffect(() => {
    console.log(`gettingAzure: ${userData!.cpf}`);

    if (!loginData) {
      navigation.navigate('Login');
    } else {
      loginGet(userData!.cpf, loginData!.access_token)
        .then((data: UserAzureInterface) => {
          console.log(JSON.stringify(data));
          dispatchUserAzureSuccess(data, dispatch);
        })
        .catch(_error => {});
    }
  }, []);

  if (azurePending || !azureData) {
    return <LoadingModal />;
  }

  return (
    <ProfileIndexTemplate
      onSubmit={onSubmit}
      userData={userData}
      loginAzure={azureData}
    />
  );
```